# Preventing partition column from appearing in exported data

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have an external table partitioned on Timestamp column which is of datetime type. So the external table definition looks like this:-

```
.create external table external_mytable (mydata:dynamic,Timestamp:datetime)
kind=blob
partition by bin(Timestamp,1d)
dataformat=json
( 
    h@'https://<mystorage>.blob.core.windows.net/<mycontainer>;<storagekey>'
)
```

The source table for the export is mytable which has a bunch of columns but I am only interested in a column called mydata holding actual payload and other columns year, month & day, which are required to drive partitioning.

My export looks like this:-

```
.export async to table  external_mytable <| mysourcetable | project mydata,Timestamp=make_datetime(year,month,day)
```

Now in this case I don't ideally want Timestamp column to be part of actual exported JSON data. I am forced to specify it because this column is driving partitioning logic. Is there any way to avoid Timestamp appearing in the exported data and still be used in determining partitioning in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the ask Dhiraj, this is on our backlog. Feel feel to open similar asks on our [user voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/915733-azure-data-explorer) where we can update once it is complete.

Comment: is it implemented yet?

Comment: Is the motivation here to save cost or something else?

Comment: we export data to blobs in partitioned manner (e.g. year/month/day/hour ) and then try to built external partitioned hive tables pointing to those blobs -- the issue is that since the external hive tables are also partitioned on the same columns (year,month,day,hour) , we need to define those partition columns as regular columns in the hive schema (with different names) unnecessarily because those columns exist in data. We don't need those values in data since the very structure of partitions imply their values. This basically makes the solution look messy.

Comment: is this implemented yet? If so , pls point me to the correct doc

Comment: It appears that virtual columns can be defined for external tables but not supported for export. This makes exported data redundant because certain columns appear in blob path also as well as actual data file of the exported data